# Microsoft Identity Platform dependency configuration in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have created an Azure App Service built in .NET 6.0 and published it to Azure. In the Publish page it has detected a service dependency on the Microsoft Identity Platform and I am trying to configure this. It runs through the Wizard, and on the last step it tries to run the following command:

```
dotnet msidentity --update-project --tenant-id {myTenantId} --username {myUsername} --client-id {myClientId} --project-file-path "C:\Projects\MyProject.csproj" --calls-graph=False --calls-downstream-api=False --code-update=true --json
```

This command fails:

```
   at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoElementsException()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Scaffolding.Shared.Project.ProjectModifierHelper.GetStartupClassName(Document programDoc) in /_/src/Shared/Microsoft.DotNet.Scaffolding.Shared/Project/ProjectModifierHelper.cs:line 94
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Scaffolding.Shared.Project.ProjectModifierHelper.IsMinimalApp(Project project) in /_/src/Shared/Microsoft.DotNet.Scaffolding.Shared/Project/ProjectModifierHelper.cs:line 50
   at Microsoft.DotNet.MSIdentity.CodeReaderWriter.ProjectModifier.AddAuthCodeAsync() in /_/src/MSIdentityScaffolding/Microsoft.DotNet.MSIdentity/CodeReaderWriter/ProjectModifier.cs:line 54
   at Microsoft.DotNet.MSIdentity.AppProvisioningTool.UpdateProject(TokenCredential tokenCredential, ApplicationParameters applicationParameters, ProjectDescription projectDescription) in /_/src/MSIdentityScaffolding/Microsoft.DotNet.MSIdentity/Tool/AppProvisioningTool.cs:line 728
   at Microsoft.DotNet.MSIdentity.AppProvisioningTool.Run() in /_/src/MSIdentityScaffolding/Microsoft.DotNet.MSIdentity/Tool/AppProvisioningTool.cs:line 143
   at Microsoft.DotNet.MSIdentity.Tool.Program.HandleUpdateProject(ProvisioningToolOptions provisioningToolOptions) in /_/tools/dotnet-msidentity/Program.cs:line 154
   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.CommandHandler.GetExitCodeAsync(Object value, InvocationContext context)
   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.ModelBindingCommandHandler.InvokeAsync(InvocationContext context)
   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<BuildInvocationChain>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<<UseParseErrorReporting>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<<UseHelp>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<<UseVersionOption>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<<UseTypoCorrections>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseSuggestDirective>b__24_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<<UseParseDirective>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<<UseDebugDirective>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<RegisterWithDotnetSuggest>b__10_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.Builder.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<<UseExceptionHandler>b__0>d.MoveNext()
ErrorFailed to configure Code.
Calling dotnet msidentity CLI tool...
ErrorFailed to configure dependency Microsoft identity platform identityapp1.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: We did have some problems with `StartupClassName` (in console apps) when upgrading to .Net 6, ended out having to specify the location of `Main` explicitly in the project

Answer (score 0):

To configure `Microsoft identity platform` in **VS 2022** with `ASP.NET Core` web app , I tried in my environment ,

- while creating an application from there we can select ***Microsoft identity platform*** as an authentication type .

[image]

- If we did not select above authentication type . Try to install `Nuget package`  called **Microsoft.Identity.Web** in your project then try to configure **MS IDENTITY PLATFORM** using your Tenant.
  [image]
- After followed the above steps it was successfully configured.

[image]

For more information please refer the below link:

- GitHub: [***Creating ASP.NET Core projects with Microsoft identity platform(Azure AD and Azure AD B2C)***](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/tools/app-provisioning-tool/vs2019-16.9-how-to-use.md)